# How to debug this prime-counting C program?

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, primes, function-definition

[image: in the image is the output I see]

This program gives me zero primes in the array after running it. This is a program that takes 2d array [n x m] then calculate how many prime numbers are there in the 2d array.

```
int isprime(int n)
{
    int k;
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;
    for (k = 2; k <= (n / 2); k++){
        if (n % k == 0)
         return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
}
int primecount(int x, int y, int a[x][y]){
    int r, c, count = 0;
    for(r = 0; r < x; r++) {
        for(c = 0; c < y; c++) {
            if(isprime(a[r][c]))
            {
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j, z;
    printf("Enter the Number of Rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the Number of Columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("\n");
    int a[n][m];
    printf("Enter the elements of the array: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
    z = primecount(n, m, a[n][m]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The Number of Prime Numbers in the array is: %d", z);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should edit your title so that it reflects your question's contents. Use "please" instead of "plz".

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: good advice, but technical writing probably should not use that word either - avoid "please", "thank you", and "help". The best questions just refers to the author in the first person: how can I do this? how can I fix it? etc.

Comment: Please edit your title for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters instead of this call

```
z = primecount(n, m, a[n][m]);
```

you need to write

```
z = primecount(n, m, a);
```

In this call of the function `isprime`  as in the call shown above

```
if(isprime(r, c, a[r][c]))
```

the expression `a[r][c]` is a scalar object of the type `int`. However the function `isprime` expects a two-dimensional array instead of a scalar object of the type `int`.

```
int isprime(int p, int q, int a[p][q])
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Just declare the function like

```
int isprime( int x );
```

and correspondingly change its definition.

The function will be called like

```
if( isprime( a[r][c] ) )
```

Pay attention to that the logic of the function `isprime` is incorrect. It returns logical true for values equal to `1` and `0` though such values are not prime numbers.

Also you need to deal with an array with elements of the type `unsigned int`. Otherwise the user can enter negative values.

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isprime(int n)
{
    int k;
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;
    for (k = 2; k <= (n / 2); k++)
    {
        if (n % k == 0)
         return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int primecount(int x, int y, int a[x][y]) //function to count prime numbers
{
    int r, c, count = 0;
    for(r = 0; r < x; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < y; c++)
        {
            if(isprime(a[r][c]))
            {
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j, z;
    printf("Enter the Number of Rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the Number of Columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("\n");

    int a[n][m];
    printf("Enter the elements of the array: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
    z = primecount(n, m, a);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The Number of Prime Numbers in the array is: %d", z);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the Number of Rows: 2
Enter the Number of Columns: 2
Enter the elements of the array: 1 2 3 4

The Number of Prime Numbers in the array is: 2
```

Comment: can you plz explain what should i do in the logic of isprime function cuz i did not understand this part,and thx for your help.

Comment: @KareemTamer You need to exclude numbers 0 and 1 from the set of prime numbers. At present your function says that such numbers are prime numbers. That is the condition of  the for loop at once evaluates to false and the control is passed to the statement return 1;

Comment: i have edited it but this time everytime it gives me zero

Comment: @KareemTamer It is not a goof idea to change code in a question when it has already an answer because this will confuse readers of the question and answers. You Forgot to change the function call.

Comment: im so sorry for the inconvenience im just new here i did not think of that. i changed it but still gives me zero.

Comment: @KareemTamer You have a typo (a redundant brace)     return 1;
}
}

Comment: @KareemTamer See my updated answer.

Comment: still after removing it it gives me zero.

Comment: @KareemTamer Do you have changed the function call in main? I can not reproduce your result.

Comment: yeah i changed it but still gives zero if u can see the image 1 in the discription u will see what happens

Comment: @KareemTamer I so not see your program. The output hides it.

Comment: oh sorry i will edit it

Comment: @KareemTamer See my appended post.

Comment: i changed the photo to see the code clearly

Comment: @KareemTamer One more see my appended answer.